# form input image goes to a new line

Tags: php, html, css, forms, user-input

when I use an image as a form input submit button, the form image goes to a new line. How can I make that image remain on the same line as a form input submit button? here is my form:

```
<form id="voteform" name="voteform" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
<INPUT TYPE="image" class="voteform" src="images/vote.png" style="float: left;" name='vote' ALT="Submit Form" onMouseOver="this.src='images/vote_link.png'"
    onMouseOut="this.src='images/vote.png'" width="35" height="20" title="Click to Vote!"></form>
```

Is there anyway to resolve this using css or something?
Thank you.

Edit: I tried using  display: inline-block; in the css but even that didn't help.. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that some parent element has a width set that you are bumping up against. You could:

1. Make the wrapping element wider
2. Make the image smaller
3. set `white-space:nowrap` on the parent element

There is nothing in the element itself that is causing it to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

put `display: inline-block;` in the voteform CSS

Comment: i already tried this but it still goes to the next line.. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

With the CSS property: `display: inline-block;` it would not go to the next line.
If it should be in the line of an element which is not within the `<form>` tag, you should also apply this property for the form element in CSS.

Comment: i already tried this but it still goes to the next line.. any idea why?

Comment: Could you give a bit more Code (not only the <form>) and also the CSS code?

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to use a background image on the element, and use :hover for your mouseover. I think this is cleaner than image-swapping with JavaScript. And the input will be an inline block just as you expect it to be.

```
<!-- html -->
​<form action="whatever.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="huh" id="button" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

/* css */
#button { background-image: url('path/to/my/first/image.png'); }
#button:hover { background-image: url('path/to/my/second/image.png'); }
```

Comment: Can you show the problem live somewhere, perhaps as a jsfiddle?